# jquery history of input select (easy)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field called email class keyup-an. I validate it easy with this, but it works or when an individual inputs the field manually. How do i make it work also for selecting historical data. when you click email and yesterday you put test@test.com, the history list drops down and you can select it, but its not a keyup.

I TRIED the same function after but with .change or .click and it didnt work. Can you guys please suggest?VALID

```
$('.keyup-an').keyup(function() {
    $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var numericReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{2,30}$/;
    if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $(this).css('background', '#FAC3C3');
        $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-1">Validationfail</span>');
    } 
    else {
        $(this).css('background', 'lightgreen');
    }
});
```

[image: jquery history]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by

```
autocomplete='off'
```

example

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

or try something like

```
$(input).autocomplete().keyup(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}).keydown(function() {
$(this).autocomplete('search', $(input).val());   
});
```

good read

[How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

Comment: Haha nice, but if possible, i would like autocomplete to still work

Comment: @Val you can on this like  `$('#form1').attr('autocomplete','off');`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want an event which gets triggered if you click on the autocomplete item.

This is a known bug, check out this article about a jquery plugin, I think this is exactly what you need:

http://furrybrains.com/2009/01/02/capturing-autofill-as-a-change-event/

Comment: Im trying to implement this to test but cant get it to work. any advice?

Comment: did you change your method to a change-event? In the suggested method,  $(this).trigger('change') is called so you need to change your method to $('.keyup-an').change(function() {.. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding your function to the keyup event.. maybe bind it to change event?
ok.. this doesn't work on some browsers it seems.. you can refer to the previous answer and use the solution, which basically creates a timer to check the values in intervals to detect changes. Forcing the browser to do a lot of work if you want the validation to happen very fast imo..  Or you could turn of autocomplete and force the user to enter the values manually like the first answer suggested.